# how to insert an image in flutter

Tags: flutter

can anyone tell me how to add image above textformfield Login?
im new into this
this is my code.

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Login")),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,

              child: Column(
                children: [
                  _emailTextField(),
                  _passwordTextField(),
                  _buttonLogin(),
                  SizedBox(height: 30,),
                  _menuRegistrasi()

                  
                ],
              ),
            ),            
          ),
        ),
      ),
      
    );
    
  }
  

  
  
  Widget _emailTextField() {
    
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email"),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      
      controller: _emailTextboxController,
      
      validator: (value){
        
        //validasi harus diisi
        if(value.isEmpty){
          return 'Email harus diisi';
        }
        return null;
      },
      
    );
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a image from the internet like this:

```
Image(
   image: NetworkImage('image url'),
 )
```

and an image from your system after making an assets folder and adding your image in that:

```
Image(image: AssetImage('assets/your image'))

flutter: //Add this to pubspec.yaml
  assets:
    - assets/background.png
```